# Log4j - Tomcat ignoring logging events with level below ERROR

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I'm trying to use log4j-1.2.16 in an application.

First of all, the application uses GWT. In development the application is deployed in the embedded jetty of the GWT plugin for Eclipse.

In development the logging works fine: I can see the log messages in the console as expected (from DEBUG to WARN in stdout and from ERROR to FATAL in stderr as configured - check `log4j.xml` configuration file bellow).

In production the application is deployed in Tomcat 7.

In production I want the messages to be logged in the `${catalina.home}/logs/app.log` daily rolling file (with level range from INFO to FATAL) plus the stdout and stderr (tomcat.stdout and tomcat.stderr) as mentioned above (check `log4j.xml` configuration file bellow).

The problem is that when I deploy the application in tomcat any log message with level bellow ERROR is not logged (not to the rolling file nor to the stdout). ERROR and FATAL messages are logged correctly though (to the rolling file and to the stderr).

Does anyone know why this is happening or have had the same problem?

Bellow you can see the log4j.xml configuration file. It looks fine to me and it works in jetty.

```
<throwableRenderer class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer" />

<!-- daily rolling log file -->
<appender name="LOGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/app.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />

    <!-- date and context come from a custom prefix -->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %m%n" />
    </layout>

</appender>


<!-- stdout -->
<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />

    <!-- date and context come from a custom prefix -->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %m%n" />
    </layout>

    <!-- range: TRACE to WARN -->
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="levelMin" value="TRACE" />
        <param name="levelMax" value="WARN" />
    </filter>

</appender>

<!-- stderr -->
<appender name="stderr" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.err" />

    <!-- date and context come from a custom prefix -->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %m%n" />
    </layout>

    <!-- range: ERROR to FATAL -->
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="levelMin" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="levelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>

</appender>

<!-- disable non-application loggers with level below ERROR -->

<!-- axis -->
<category name="org.apache.axis">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
</category>

<!-- jasper -->
<category name="org.apache.jasper">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
</category>

<!-- jetty -->
<category name="org.mortbay">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
</category>

<!-- gwt -->
<category name="com.google.gwt">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
</category>

<!-- the root category -->
<root>
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: stackoverflow removed the enclosing `log4j:configuration` tags. File structure is not the problem.